# How to use Angular Material MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS injection token

Tags: angular, angular-material

What is the way to use the MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS injection token, or the const AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT to customize mat-autocomplete. These constants, among others are exposed in the public API [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) but no documentation on how to use them

Answer (score 5):

Add `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` to your module's `providers` array like this:

```
providers: [
  // ...
  {provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {autoActiveFirstOption: false}}
]
```

As for the other constants, I'm not sure you can adjust them. You'll probably have to play around with the CSS styles, see for instance [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3810) for adjusting the panel height.

Comment: Thanx Jeto, I though that token would help me set the hight of each option as well. Truth is, setting the heigh with css is a no brainer. The problem is that when navigating the list with the arrow keys, the list scrolles up much faster then needed because material thinks every option is 48 px height. Thats why I need to change the option hight constant, for the scroll strategy to work proparly.

Comment: @Gidon did you found how to override the constants values?

Comment: @MatiasFernandezMartinez nope

Answer (score 1):

It's quite weird, why such a needed option like the height of item (option) isn't defined as input.

Because without changing of `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT` we will get a bug (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18030)

Here is a possible solution:

Step 1. Change style.

It's the easiest moment. We can just change the global style. Let's use 24px instead 48px

```
mat-option.mat-option{
    position: relative;
    height: 24px!important;
    line-height: 24px!important;
    max-height: 24px!important;
}
```

Step 2. Overwrite original `_scrollToOption` method of `MatAutocompleteTrigger`

The pain is located here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/49a1324acc05cec1c5ff28d729abfe590f6772dd/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts line 498, method `_scrollToOption`.

This method takes two hardcoded constants (`AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT`, `AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT`) and uses it to calculate new scroll position. Sure, if you have not 48px, but less or more - it will work incorrectly.

So, we have to **overwrite** this method.

The most elegant way to do it - using `Directive` (keep in mind, we can get access with `@ViewChild()` to `MatAutocompleteTrigger` and change it in the scope of a parent component, but it's not a reusable solution).

Step 2.1. Create directive

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Host, Self, Optional, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger, AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT, AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT } from '@angular/material';
import {
  _countGroupLabelsBeforeOption,
  _getOptionScrollPosition
} from '@angular/material/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[matAutocompleteTriggerAccessor]',
})

export class DirectiveAccessor implements OnInit {

    @Input() optionHeight: number = AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT;
    @Input() panelHeight: number = AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT;

    constructor(
      @Host() @Self() @Optional() public _refTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
      if (this._refTrigger === undefined || this._refTrigger === null) {
        return;
      }
      this._refTrigger['_scrollToOption'] = this._scrollToOption.bind(this._refTrigger, this.optionHeight, this.panelHeight);
    }

    private _scrollToOption(
      this: MatAutocompleteTrigger,
      optionHeight: number,
      panelHeight: number,
    ): void {
      const index = this.autocomplete._keyManager.activeItemIndex || 0;
      const labelCount = _countGroupLabelsBeforeOption(
        index,
        this.autocomplete.options,
        this.autocomplete.optionGroups
      );
      if (index === 0 && labelCount === 1) {
        this.autocomplete._setScrollTop(0);
      } else {
        const newScrollPosition = _getOptionScrollPosition(
          index + labelCount,
          optionHeight,
          this.autocomplete._getScrollTop(),
          panelHeight
        );
        this.autocomplete._setScrollTop(newScrollPosition);
      }
  }
}
```

- So, we use "original" code of `_scrollToOption` method. Only one thing we do - avoid using constants: `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT`, `AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT`
- instead these constants we are adding two inputs `optionHeight` and `panelHeight`
- as defaults values for new inputs, we are using values of `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT`, `AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT`

Step 2.2. Add directive and addition inputs

Now we can modify our template and add a new directive and addition inputs.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matAutocompleteTriggerAccessor [optionHeight]="24">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**Note**. Our directive `matAutocompleteTriggerAccessor` and input `optionHeight` should be attached to `<input>`, but not to `<mat-autocomplete>`.

And that's all. Now all works as it should.

Here is a full solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cn4ox8