# How can I override Angular Material default options using "Injection Tokens" (or some other means)

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular-material

[The Angular Material documentation indicates](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#constants) that certain default options may be overridden using an "Injection token":

> #### Constants
>
> `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`
>
> Injection token to be used
>   to override the default options for `mat-autocomplete`.
>
> ```
> const MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS: InjectionToken<MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions>;
> ```

It looks to expose options for panel height, option height, and a few other things. However it is a little vague on how to implement. I've been referencing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029965/how-to-use-angular-material-mat-autocomplete-default-options-injection-token) and [this guide](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-material-form-field-appearance/) and I feel I'm getting closer, but it still is not working. This is where I am presently:

```
import { MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions } from '@angular/material';

const appearance: MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions = {
  // here I would like to override `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT` and `AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT`
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: appearance,
    },
  ],
export class SearchComponent { /* etc. */ }
```

The properties `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT` and `AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT` do not seem to exist on `MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions` interface, so this must be incorrect.

The documentation specifies that "Injection Tokens" must be used, but neither the examples I've seen, nor the Material documentation itself resembles [the Angular documentation on InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken). Is putting it in the  `providers` array in some way related to injection tokens? It is very vague.

Within their `Constants` section, many Material components indicate this type of behavior is attainable, so:

#### How can these Providers / Injection Tokens be used to modify default options?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by changing css styles for the panel. 
Look into this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3810 for setting panel height.
as MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions has only one property, I dont think you can change other properties.

and I see the parameters declared as constants, So you may try by changing css styles.

```
/** The height of each autocomplete option. */
export declare const AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT = 48;
/** The total height of the autocomplete panel. */
export declare const AUTOCOMPLETE_PANEL_HEIGHT = 256;
```

Hope this helps.